# Proper way to handle wxwidget events with std::thread

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wxwidgets

Been trying to figure out how to properly handle custom events in conjunction with std::thread, haven't been able to find any code without wxThread. As i understand i need to use wxQueueEvent, but my problem is how to get the wxEvtHandler pointer to the class holding the thread. The bellow code passes a pointer of the class where i have the "onErrorEvent" function, this compiles and works, but I'm not sure if that's a "legal" way of doing it. It feels like a bad idea to use the pointer that way idk. All i want to know is if it will work hehe, doesn't need to be perfect textbook worthy code.

```
#include "cMain.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

const int myEvtId=10000;
const int writeEvtId=10001;
wxDEFINE_EVENT(MY_EVT,wxCommandEvent);
wxDEFINE_EVENT(WRITE_EVT,wxCommandEvent);

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(cMain,wxFrame)
    EVT_COMMAND(myEvtId,MY_EVT,cMain::onErrorEvent)
    EVT_COMMAND(writeEvtId,WRITE_EVT,cMain::onWriteEvent)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

class threadClass
{
    public:
        void startThread(wxEvtHandler *evtHandle)
        {
            threadState=true;
            thr=thread(&threadClass::threadFn,this,evtHandle);
        }

        void endThread()
        {
            if(threadState)
            {
                threadState=false;
                thr.join();
            }
        }

    private:
        bool threadFn(wxEvtHandler *evtHandle)
        {
            while(threadState)
            {               
                if(error)   
                {
                    //Error occurred
                    wxCommandEvent *evt=new wxCommandEvent(MY_EVT,myEvtId);                 
                    wxQueueEvent(evtHandle,evt);
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Otherwise write data
                    wxCommandEvent *evt=new wxCommandEvent(WRITE_EVT,writeEvtId);
                    evt->SetString("Data to be written");
                    wxQueueEvent(evtHandle,evt);
                }

                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
            }

            return true;
        }

    private:
        thread thr;
        bool threadState=false;
        bool error=false;
};

threadClass thrClass;

cMain::cMain() : wxFrame(nullptr,wxID_ANY,"wxWidgets template",wxPoint(30,30),wxSize(420,520))
{
    txt1=new wxTextCtrl(this,wxID_ANY,"",wxPoint(20,20),wxSize(300,400),wxTE_READONLY | wxTE_MULTILINE);
    wxButton *btn1=new wxButton(this,wxID_ANY,"Button 1",wxPoint(160,430),wxSize(80,40));   

    thrClass.startThread(this);
}

cMain::~cMain()
{
    thrClass.endThread();
}

void cMain::onErrorEvent(wxCommandEvent &evt)
{
    //Handle Error
    thrClass.endThread();
}

void cMain::onWriteEvent(wxCommandEvent &evt)
{
    //Write data
    txt1->AppendText(evt.GetString()+'\n');
}
```

I'm using std:thread so it's compatible with existing code I've already written, so I'd rather not rewrite it with wxThread instead.
//Benji

**Edit - I revised the code to include my method of printing to the textCtrl ui element.

Comment: as ong as you don't call any GUI method inside a thread - this is a way. Pass a pointer. Try it. See if it works. If not - come back and explain what didn't

Comment: This is just the important parts, the code that's working does "AppendText()" on a "wxTextCtrl". The way I'm doing that is passing a pointer to the textCtrl to the "threadClass" and then the "threadFn". I've done this in the past, only without a event handler and has always worked. Could it be problematic doing it this way? Has worked flawlessly so far.

Comment: you mean you called 1AppendText()` inside thread? Don't. wxWidgets classes are NOT MT-safe. And if you want to use std::thread - this is the way to do it... Unless you can show that it won't.

Comment: Is there any way to call something like AppendText() in a thread? Like for example wxThread? Otherwise if a thread wanted to write to a textCtrl, would it have to do it via a custom event or something?

Comment: `Is there any way to call something like AppendText() in a thread?` Please read what I wrote very carefully .Understand it. Then read it 10 times more. And then one more time. And let me repeat it here ust for you - `wxWidgets classes are NOT MT SAFE`. What is not clear about that?  The way to do it is to send an wxThreadEvent bac to the GUI thread. Or you can use {wx}timer but it won't guarantee the execution will happen in the right moment.

Comment: Ok sorry, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: On top of Igor's comments, https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_thread.html

Comment: Ok but to get back to the original question, the code above as i have revised it, is "legal" and not problematic correct?